# configuring web.py in nginx.. confusion

Tags: python, nginx, web.py

Hi I am new with nginx server, and I have uploaded my `index.py` file at `/var/www/pyth/index.py` ...

I am a little bit confused because in my local I can run freely 
`python index.py` and access `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

I was wondering how can I do that in nginx, I have run `python index.py` but I can't access to `mysite.com:8080`

this is my config in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;`

    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index index.php index.py index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/mysite.com;
    index index.php index.py index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied reques$
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    ...
```

does anyone has an idea about my case? any help will be appreciated.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up either a [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (or similar), or a [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) in nginx.
The option with UWSGI is better because it'll use the protocol designed for working with web-servers; though it's a bit harder to set up than just proxying everything via nginx.

### proxy_pass

web.py has a web-server just for the development purposes, it shouldn't be used in production environment because it's really slow and inefficient in that case, and using `proxy_pass` wouldn't be a great idea if you are planning to release it.

With proxy_pass, you leave the 127.0.0.1:8080 server online, and then in nginx (on the same server), set up like that:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

The `proxy_pass` option redirects everything to the web.py server at 127.0.0.1:8080, the other ones - redirect the data about the connection (IP of the connected client and the host that was used for the connection on the nginx's side)

### UWSGI

Using UWSGI, in short, is like that:

1) install `uwsgi` using your distro's package manager, or a `pip`, or using `setup.py install`.

2) in nginx, set up a server that will pass everything to the UWSGI server:
    server {
        listen       80;

```
    location / {
        include   uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

3) Then, in your web.py application (let's suppose it's called `yourappfile.py`), instead of `app.run()`, use:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

You can still have `app.run()`, just make sure to put it inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block; and make sure the `application = app.wsgifunc()` is outside so UWSGI could see it.

Then start a UWSGI server:

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file yourappfile.py
```

Take a look at these manuals, it may help you:

- [UWSGI Quickstart](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html)
- [Web.py running on the nginx uwsgi](http://www.programering.com/a/MzN5ETMwATU.html)
- [Deployment of Web.py Applications Using uWSGI and
  Nginx](http://fartersoft.com/blog/2011/06/30/deployment-of-web-py-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx/)
- [UWSGI Wiki - Examples](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example)

Comment: i got an error of `uwsgi: invalid option -- 'w' getopt_long() error` .. do you have any example of the `xml` ?

Comment: @gadss I use ini files myself, you can check either of the links above; [UWSGI Quickstart](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html) seems to be the most updated one.